# Error occurs when trying to filter 2D arrays and push them back into google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The process I want to achieve here is to get data into a 2D array, filter it out, then only grab selected column data within the filtered array and push it back into a new tab in the same google sheet. Each process is commented, so you can follow what I am doing.

```
function copyToAndFrom() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("PendingX");//sheet with imported data
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Resolved");//archive sheet
  var lr = s2.getLastRow()+1;//get last row of archive sheet + 1
  var dList = s1.getRange("PendingX!G2:G").getValues(); // Gets all the values of that specific column
  var dLast = dList.filter(String).length; //Gets the length of dList.

  var myArray = []; // A 2D array. I want a 12 column, dLast number of rows array.
  myArray.length = dLast;
  var tempArr = []; // Secondary array to get the filtered data from myArray array.
  var filteredArr = []; // Get only specific data from tempArr array.

  // myArray = s1.getRange('PendingX!D2:O').getValues();
  // The the above comment is the original sheet import with 400+ rows but for testing, Ive disabled it and assigned manually as below.                 
  myArray = [["Pending", , "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwy", "xzz", "aaa"], 
      ["Resolved", , "aabc", "adef", "aghi", "ajkl", "amno", "apqr", "astu", "avwy", "axzz", "aaaa"],
      ["Pending", , "babc", "bdef", "bghi", "bjkl", "bmno", "bpqr", "bstu", "bvwy", "bxzz", "baaa"]];

  var myrowindex, myString, mycolumnindex;
  tempArr[myrowindex] = [];
  for (myrowindex in myArray) {  //Loops through the number of rows in myArray.
    myString = myArray[myrowindex][0];
    if (myString === "Pending") {
      for (mycolumnindex in myArray[myrowindex]) { //Loops through each column of a row in myArray.
        var myColumnValue = myArray[myrowindex][mycolumnindex]; //Loads each component of myArray to a string.
        tempArr[myrowindex].push(myColumnValue); //Push the string into the tempArr array.
      }

      myColumnValue = null;
      myString = null;
    }
  }

  for (myrowindex in tempArr){  //Load data from columns 0,3,10 and 11 into filteredArr array.
    filteredArr.push(tempArr[myrowindex][0]);
    filteredArr.push(tempArr[myrowindex][3]);
    filteredArr.push(tempArr[myrowindex][11]);
    filteredArr.push(tempArr[myrowindex][12]);
  }

  Logger.log(tempArr.length);  // must be less than myArray.length but it is not.
  Logger.log(tempArr[0].length); // must be equal to myArray[0].length but it is not.
  Logger.log(tempArr); //Doesnt store data in a 2D Array but has to.

  //CODE FOR STORING DATA TO SHEET:
  for (var row in filteredArr) { //Loops through the number of rows in filteredArr.
    for (var col in filteredArr[row]) { //Loops through each column of a row in filteredArr.
      var myColumnValue = tempArr[row][col]; //Loads each component of filteredArr to a string.
      final = s2.getRange(2,1,row,col).setValue(myColumnValue); //Push the string into the sheet.
    }
  }
}
```

Error after recent changes:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "push" of undefined. (line 30, file "CopyToFromScript")

---

CURRENT LOG OUTPUTS AND EXPECTED LOG OUTPUTS:

Current Logger for `tempArr.length`:

```
[19-02-01 19:25:08:933 IST] 22.0
```

Expected Logger for `tempArr.length`:

```
[19-02-01 19:25:08:933 IST] 2.0
```

Current Logger for `tempArr[0].length`:

```
[19-02-01 19:25:08:934 IST] 12.0
```

Expected Logger for `tempArr[0].length`:

```
[19-02-01 19:25:08:933 IST] 12.0
```

Current Logger for `tempArr`:

```
[19-02-01 19:25:08:935 IST] [Pending, abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr, stu, vwy, xzz, aaa, Pending, babc, bdef, bghi, bjkl, bmno, bpqr, bstu, bvwy, bxzz, baaa]
```

Expected Logger for `tempArr`:

```
[19-02-01 19:25:08:935 IST] [[Pending, abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr, stu, vwy, xzz, aaa], [Pending, babc, bdef, bghi, bjkl, bmno, bpqr, bstu, bvwy, bxzz, baaa]]
```

Current Logger for `filteredArr`:

```
[19-02-01 19:24:35:773 IST] [P, d, null, null, a, null, null, null, d, null, null, null, g, null, null, null, j, null, null, null, m, null, null, null, p, null, null, null, s, null, null, null, v, null, null, null, x, null, null, null, a, null, null, null, P, d, null, null, b, c, null, null, b, f, null, null, b, i, null, null, b, l, null, null, b, o, null, null, b, r, null, null, b, u, null, null, b, y, null, null, b, z, null, null, b, a, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Expected Logger for `filteredArr`:

```
[19-02-01 19:24:35:773 IST] [[Pending, def, xzz, aaa], [Pending, bdef, bxzz, baaa]]
```

Comment: What error do you get? What output does the above code generate? Answers to these question will help others understand your question.

Comment: tempArr[myrowindex] = [12] is an array but tempArr.push(myColumnData) is a value from myArray so tempArr is a mixture of arrays and single values

Comment: The error message includes the line it occurs on. Where is this error? Help us help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also note that assigning to an index means that you can make `tempArr` **"sparse"**.

Comment: I haven't tried to test your code but several things are incorrect  1) var myArray = [dLast][12]; yields undefined.  You can not size arrays this way.   You could say var myArray = []; and myArray.length = dLast; but you still need to initialize each array and sub arrary to size 12.  2) tempArr[myrowindex] = [12]; will create an array of 1 value (12) in each myrowindex.  Instead you should do this tempArr[myrowindex] = []; and move it outside the for loop  3) then inside the for loop tempArr[myrowindex].push(myColumnData);

Comment: Previously, the problem was that I did not get any errors but the results were not what I expected, and the final set of code for storing data back to the spreadsheet doesn't do anything. At this point, I have no clue what could be the problem.

After implementing changes suggested by TheWizEd, I am facing this error when executing the code:
TypeError: Cannot call method "push" of undefined. (line 30, file "CopyToFromScript")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. It was associated with properly defining the 2D Arrays within the loops. I have included the fixed portion of the code for anyone who'd like to check.

```
var myrowindex, myString, mycolumnindex, validmyrowindex = 0;
for (myrowindex in myArray) {  
    myString = myArray[myrowindex][0];
    if (myString === "Resolved") {
        tempArr[validmyrowindex] = [];
        for (mycolumnindex = 0; mycolumnindex < 12; mycolumnindex++){
            if(tempArr[validmyrowindex] != undefined) {
                var myColumnValue = myArray[myrowindex][mycolumnindex];
                tempArr[validmyrowindex][mycolumnindex] = myColumnValue;
            } else {
                var myColumnValue = myArray[myrowindex][mycolumnindex];
                tempArr[validmyrowindex] = myColumnValue;
            }     
        myColumnValue = null;
        myString = null;
        }
    } else {validmyrowindex--}
        validmyrowindex++
}
```

Everything below this point from the original code is redundant. It was replaced with an iteration of the above with fixed columns. And the basic `setValues(array)` function was used for storing the entire array into the sheet. Thanks for your valuable explanation and support, everyone.